# Xcode Version 12.5 (12E262) / Swift layout constraint errors - tableview with dynamic sizing textview

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, constraints, uitextview

I have a tableview which has dynamic sizing cells - because they contain a textview. Everything displays correctly but I am receiving some stubborn constraints errors.

I have tried modifying and removing in every way I can think but they either persist or break functionality ( ie. removing errors breaks functionality)

[image: Tableview Cell causing errors]

The errors seem to point to an issue with the bottom 'task' cell.

These are the constraints that I am using for the bottom cell.

[image: Constraints for bottom cell]

Errors below :

```
[LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x282221590 UITableViewCellContentView:0x106079640.bottom == UITextView:0x1058cc000.bottomMargin + 8   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x282221630 V:|-(2)-[UITextView:0x1058cc000]   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x106079640 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x282222170 'UIView-bottomMargin-guide-constraint' V:[UILayoutGuide:0x283818a80'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide']-(8)-|   (active, names: '|':UITextView:0x1058cc000 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x282221e50 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UITableViewCellContentView:0x106079640.height == 0   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x282222170 'UIView-bottomMargin-guide-constraint' V:[UILayoutGuide:0x283818a80'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide']-(8)-|   (active, names: '|':UITextView:0x1058cc000 )>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Could this just be a bug or is there something that I am doing wrong ?

I have also tried wtfautolayout.com and the results are a little confusing also.

Any help or ideas appreciated

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using stack views, you will save a couple of constraints and of course the design will also look a little better, and your error mentions that it is the constraint of bottom = task text view.bottommargin + 8.

Likewise, on the design screen, your constraints may appear in red and it tells you the first two that contradict or are not satisfied in your design.

Comment: Just to point out that I managed to fix the error - details in my answer to come - but which objects would you suggest using stackViews for ? Just objects within a cell or all objects , content view and below ? I am not seeing any red on the design screen. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the errors by changing the priority on one of the constraints

[image]

[image]

A kind person from a Facebook group sent me this useful link :

http://aplus.rs/2017/one-solution-for-90pct-auto-layout/?fbclid=IwAR2bG95eNQScExFUtjL1H5dOrzjY0FTrScET--hcttzYP3hyDJVbiRipfOA